# Find out what MAC addresses are connected to each physical LAN port of router

Tags: hardware, router, port, lan

I'm managing a router running `Linux 3.10.87-rt80-Cavium-Octeon`

On the router's GUI, there's a "Switch ports" page where I can see all ethernet ports (4 LAN - 2 WAN) and their corresponding link negotiation info.

However there's nowhere I can find which MAC address is connected to each physical port on the router.

I've googled and searched here to see if there was a linux command that could achieve this but could not find anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Read `man arp` ("Address Resolution Protocol) and do `arp -an`.

Comment: What kind of a router is it? Does the Linux side see all the ports as separate interfaces? The home routers I've seen have the OS only see one or two ports, with the rest behind a separate switch chip. Which would mean you need dig the information out of the chip. Might be the system has a tool or a driver for it.

Comment: @waltinator: I've read man arp, but it doesn't provide what I need. -a only shows all hosts and -n does not resolve names; how is that supposed to tell me to which physical LAN port is the MAC address connected to?

Comment: @ilkkachu: Hello! It's an Edgemarc 2900 router. The interface only sees VLANS and WAN ports, but no LAN ports.

Comment: On a "normal" (ie: software) Linux bridge this information is available with `bridge fdb` (more precisely `bridge fdb show state dynamic`). But chances are there's hardware acceleration, using DSA or switchdev architecture, so behavior might differ.